# EF Core - Error message when calling SaveChanges(): "The association between entity types has been severed, ..."

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, savechanges

I have following data model

```
public class SportEvent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int QualifierLeaderboardId { get; set; }
    public Leaderboard QualifierLeaderboard { get; set; }
    public int FinalLeaderboardId { get; set; }
    public Leaderboard FinalLeaderboard { get; set; }
}

public class Leaderboard
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Ranking> Rankings { get; set; }
    public int LeaderboardSportEventId { get; set; }
    public SportEvent LeaderboardSportEvent { get; set; }
}
```

One SportEvent has exactly two Leaderboards - one for the qualifier and one for the final event. One Leaderboard has exactly one SportsEvent.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SportEvent>()
                .HasOne(s => s.QualifierLeaderboard)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<SportEvent>(s => s.QualifierLeaderboardId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

    modelBuilder.Entity<SportEvent>()
                .HasOne(s => s.FinalLeaderboard)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<SportEvent>(s => s.FinalLeaderboardId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Leaderboard>()
                .HasOne(l => l.LeaderboardSportEvent)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Leaderboard>(l => l.LeaderboardSportEventId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
}
```

So I configured two relations from SportEvent to Leaderboard and one navigation property on Leaderboard.

```
SportEvent sportEvent = new SportEvent();
Leaderboard finalLeaderboard = new Leaderboard() { LeaderboardSportEvent = sportEvent};
Leaderboard qualificationLeaderboard = new Leaderboard() { LeaderboardSportEvent = sportEvent };
sportEvent.FinalLeaderboard = finalLeaderboard;
sportEvent.QualifierLeaderboard= qualificationLeaderboard;

try
{
    TestingContext context = new TestingContext();
    context.SportEvents.Add(sportEvent);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

When I try to add data and save the changes to the database, following exception occurs.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The association between entity types 'SportEvent' and 'Leaderboard' has been severed, 
but the relationship is either marked as required or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. 
If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, configure the relationship to use cascade deletes. 
Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key values.'
```

I read already a lot of other posts but was not able to solve it. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: While adding data are you adding foreign objects as well? or setting foreign keys

Comment: It's just happens if I execute the sample code above. Create two Leaderoboard objects, add it to the SportEvent, then add the SportEvent to the context and save the context...

Comment: Imagine that you have one SportEvent and its two assocciated Leaderboards in the DB. What should happen to the Entities in the DB, if you (a) delete one of the Leaderboards or (b) the SportEvent. How does that relate to (x) the OnDelete behaviour or (y) the nullability of the FK-Id an NavigationProperties?

Comment: @GWimpassinger Not sure if I get your point: If the SportEvent is deleted, the two Leaderboard can be deleted either. Deleting a Leaderboard which is assigned to a SportEvent shall not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign to properties of your `SportEvent` its related entities, it doesn't mean you don't have to add them to the database. When you save changes, `DbContext` finds a broken relationship and throws an exception. You should save all entities:

```cs
SportEvent sportEvent = new SportEvent();
Leaderboard finalLeaderboard = new Leaderboard() { LeaderboardSportEvent = sportEvent, LeaderboardSportEventId = sportEvent.Id };
Leaderboard qualificationLeaderboard = new Leaderboard() { LeaderboardSportEvent = sportEvent, LeaderboardSportEventId = sportEvent.Id };
sportEvent.FinalLeaderboard = finalLeaderboard;
sportEvent.FinalLeaderboardId = finalLeaderboard.Id;
sportEvent.QualifierLeaderboard = qualificationLeaderboard;
sportEvent.QualifierLeaderboardId = qualificationLeaderboard.Id;

try
{
    TestingContext context = new TestingContext();
    context.SportEvents.Add(sportEvent);
    context.Leaderboards.Add(finalLeaderboard);
    context.Leaderboards.Add(qualificationLeaderboard);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for you reply. 
Indeed I did as advised, but the same exception (InvalidOperationException, 'The associaltion between SportEvent and Laederboard has been severed, but... " is thrown when I add the "finalLeaderboard" to the context...

Comment: @Norbert Updated my answer, try the new code.

Comment: Tried it and it still throws the same exception...

Comment: Then try modifying `OnModelCreating`. Not sure if it helps, but maybe use `WithOne(l => l.LeaderboardSportEvent)` instead of just `WithOne()` when configuring sport events and `WithOne(s => s.FinalLeaderboard).WithOne(s => s.QualifierLeaderboard)` when configuring leaderboards?

Comment: Just check it but "WithOne" can be only used once, so "WithOne(s => s.FinalLeaderboard).WithOne(s => s.QualifierLeaderboard)" is incorrect synatx...